# Como sería la expresion regular de este lenguaje en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo lo siguiente

```
P1 = { x ∊ {a,e,i}* / x no tiene dos a juntas}
```

y necesito encontrar su expresión regular y su expresion regular en javascript
no he podido resolverlo

Comment: Qué lenguaje es ese?

Comment: Es un lenguaje cualquiera, usando teoria de autómatas

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta anterior no considera `aea`. Considera opcionalmente la a en el medio

Esta expresión es mejor

`^(a$|ae|ai|e|i)*$`

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa: `^(?!.*aa)[aei]*$`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/AEogn3/1/)

**Explicado:**

```
^                # Inicio de línea/string
   (?!.*aa)      # No debe seguir cualquier cosa (.*) y (aa)
   [aei]*        # a,e,i repetidos cualquier número de veces
$                # Final de línea/string
```